# EF Core Left Join creates exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Hi I have a trouble with Ef Core even first step of my query as below.

```
var result = await _mrcRepository.Query()
            .GroupJoin(_expenseRepository.Query(),
                x => x.CoverCode,
                y => y.Code,
                (x, y) => new { x, Expense = y }) //that 'y' occurs the error.
            .SelectMany(x => x.Expense.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new {x,y})//not that
            .ToListAsync();
```

I code left join via EF Core many times as above but this time,I stuned and it's throw :

> An error occured while executing the message. System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'y' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Merchant.Model.Entity.ExpenseInfo]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I can't code it with eager load due to I need to _expenseRepository in one more left join but now I'm fail in even first step.If I fix first step, I'll continue to code it.
Am I making a mistake ? I couldn't figure it out. Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Maybe rename each of your `x` & `y` parameters so you can work out which one it's complaining about.

Comment: nothing changed but after some research I found this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/22254#issuecomment-926128738) @JeremyLakeman Its made me more confused.

Answer (score 0):

While EF Core is compiling a query, multiple `.Select` projections will be inlined. eg;

```cs
db.something.Select(x => new {x.A, x.B, x.C})
    .Select(y => new {X = y.A, Y = y.B + y.C})

// would become something equivalent to;
Expression<...> projection = x => new {X = x.A, Y = x.B + x.C};
```

But for some reason in your case, the final projection is something like;

```cs
Expression<...> projection = x => new { y };
```

The information about what this `y` value represents has been lost during the compilation process.

So here's my theory.

I suspect this is due to your `(x, y) => new {x, y}` expression, which is attempting to pass an `IEnumerable<ExpenseInfo> y` value into the final projection unmodified.

This is not an operation that this `.SelectMany` method is designed to handle. Doing nothing goes against the intended use case of that method, so it's understandable that the EF Core developers have not tested it.

Perhaps applying some method to transform the results would work?

```cs
(x, y) => new {x, y = y.ToList()}
```